# Array attribute of class containing "random" values when accessed via a pointer from another class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, class-attributes

I have a class that has an array of chars as an attribute.

```
class ClassA{
public:

  ClassA( char *fileName );

  char charArray[13][2];
};
```

`ClassA` constructor reads in 26 values from a file, and loads them
into `charArray` as follows.

```
ClassA::ClassA( fileName ){
   ifstream file;
   file.open( fileName );
   int contactOne, contactTwo;
   int pair=0;

   while( !file.eof() ){
     file >> contactOne;
     file >> contactTwo;
     if( !file.eof() ){
       charArray[pair][0] = (contactOne+65); // convert to Alpha UpperCase
       charArray[pair][1] = (contactTwo+65); // conv to Alpha UpperCase
       pair++;
     }
   }
}
```

`ClassA` is initialised in the constructor of another class, `ClassB` where `ClassB` contains a pointer to a `ClassA` object, allowing `ClassA` to be stored as an attribute of `ClassB`.

```
class ClassA; // forward derive
class ClassB{
  public:
  ClassB( char **argv );

  ClassA *a_class
};
```

ClassB's constructor:

```
ClassB::ClassB( argv ){
  ClassA a( argv[1] );
  a_class = &a;
}
```

In `main`, i'm testing the association of `ClassA` in `ClassB`. 
In a forloop I `cout` all the values in `charArray` in the following way.

```
int main( int argc, char **argv ){
  ClassB b_class( argv );

  for( int i=0; i < 13; i++ ){
     cout << b_class.a_class->charArray[i][0] << endl;
     cout << b_class.a_class->charArray[i][1] << endl;
  }
}
```

When I construct `ClassA` outside of `ClassB`, `cout << a.charArray[x][y];` works perfectly, outputting the various uppercase alphabet symbols from `charArray`.

Indeed, even when I add the `cout << a.charArray[x][y];` statement to the `ClassA` constructor and initialise `ClassA` using `ClassB` constructor, the correct values are being loaded into `charArray`, and the uppercase alphabet symbols are output.

However, when I execute what I have in main, the output from `charArray` is very strange. The first few values of the array are as expected, but the last values are somewhat random, usually randomly placed blank values and question marks. It is as if, somehow the pointer has caused the values loaded into `charArray` to be out of the correct range, or I am somehow accessing the wrong memory locations.

Any help would be much appreciated. Am I accessing `ClassA` in a weird way? Is there a preferred way of having other classes as attributes to some class?

Unusual Output:

```
A
E
B
J
C
M
D
Z

?
?
?
y
```

Usual output:

```
A
E
B
J
C
M
D
Z
F
L
G
Y
H
X
I
V
K
W
N
R
O
Q
P
U
S
T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClassA a( argv[1] );` defines `a` as a local variable that will be destroyed and its memory rendered invalid on exit from the `ClassB` constructor, leaving `a_class` pointing at garbage.

Since you need a longer lifespan for `a_class` you will have to `new ClassA(argv[1]);` and ensure it is `delete`d. I recommend looking into [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

## but...

Why do this in the first place? Instead since `ClassA` has no dependency on `ClassB`, `ClassA` can be formally defined or its header file included before `ClassB` is defined. Then you can remove the forward definition and:

```
class ClassB{
  public:
  ClassB( char **argv );

  ClassA a_class
};

ClassB::ClassB( argv ):a_class(argv[1]){
}
```

To make the whole pointer mess go away.

## Off topic:

`while( !file.eof() )` and its ilk almost never work the way you're expecting. Read more here: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

```
while( file >> contactOne >> contactTwo ){
    charArray[pair][0] = (contactOne+65); // convert to Alpha UpperCase
    charArray[pair][1] = (contactTwo+65); // conv to Alpha UpperCase
    pair++;
}
```

Should do what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I Tried this. I had to add `ClassA a_class( char *filename)` to the class declaration of `ClassB` not just `ClassA a_class;` Also, how do I then access `charArray` in `main`. Now neither `b_class.a_class.charArray` or `b_class.a_class->charArray` work.

Comment: My apologies. I missed the forward definition of `ClassA` forcing the use of a pointer. I will update.

Comment: Access from `main` in the non-pointer case would be: `cout << b_class.a_class.charArray[i][0] << endl;`

Comment: `b_class.a_class.charrArray[i][0]` gives the error `b_class.ClassB::charArray does not have a class type`. Whereas `b_class.a_class->charArray[i][0]` gives the error `base operand of -> is not a pointer`

Comment: Thanks Matteo, however, I thought i'd averted the undefined EOF read in, by  reading in a value and then checking if the `eofbit` has been altered before I execute the loop body by use of `if(!file.eof())` /* do loop stuff */`

Comment: Do  not add `ClassA a_class( char *filename)` to `ClassB` as this defined `a_class` as a function that returns `ClassA` rather than a variable of type `ClassA`. To use the non- pointer version `ClassA` must be defined before  `ClassB`. If this is not possible you will have to use a pointer-based approach.